# Sidebar Tree Collapse sidebar menu by default

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, sidebar

I'm new in bootstrap and I'm using sidebar menu group tree from http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/sidebar-menu-group-tree.
All I want is to set it collapsed by default when the page load.

Already tried to find the answer but still didn't get anything great.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove these lines:

```js
//$("#left ul.nav li.parent.active > a > span.sign").find('i:first').addClass("icon-minus");
//$("#left ul.nav li.current").parents('ul.children').addClass("in");
```

Here is [a working example](http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/o8dmP)

So your Js file becomes:

```js
!function ($) {

    $(document).on("click","#left ul.nav li.parent > a > span.sign", function(){          
        $(this).find('i:first').toggleClass("icon-minus");      
    }); 

}(window.jQuery);
```